# genpy.message.SerializationError when calling service /gazebo/set_model_configuration

Tags: ros, gazebo7, ros-kinetic, service, rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I want to implement a node, that calculates random values for the joints of my robot and publishes them. Furthermore, I want to call the service `/gazebo/set_model_configuration` to set the joints in Gazebo to these random values.
I am using Ubuntu 16.04 with ROS kinetic and Gazebo 7.14.0

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
import numpy as np
from std_msgs.msg import Float64
from std_msgs.msg import Bool
from std_msgs.msg import Header
from sensor_msgs.msg import JointState
from gazebo_msgs.srv import SetModelConfiguration
from gazebo_msgs.srv import SetModelConfigurationRequest

joint_names = ['ShoulderJRotate', 'ShoulderJSwing', 'ElbowJSwing', 'ElbowJRotate', \
    'rh_WRJ2', 'rh_WRJ1', \
    'rh_FFJ4', 'rh_FFJ3', 'rh_FFJ2', 'rh_FFJ1', \
    'rh_MFJ4', 'rh_MFJ3', 'rh_MFJ2', 'rh_MFJ1', \
    'rh_RFJ4', 'rh_RFJ3', 'rh_RFJ2', 'rh_RFJ1', \
    'rh_LFJ5', 'rh_LFJ4', 'rh_LFJ3', 'rh_LFJ2', 'rh_LFJ1', \
    'rh_THJ5', 'rh_THJ4', 'rh_THJ3', 'rh_THJ2', 'rh_THJ1']

random_joint_states_msg = JointState()
random_joint_states_msg.header = Header()
random_joint_states_msg.name = joint_names

reset_req = SetModelConfigurationRequest()
reset_req.model_name = "shadowrobot"
reset_req.urdf_param_name = "robot_description"
reset_req.joint_names = joint_names

pub_init_joint_positions = rospy.Publisher('/init_joint_positions', JointState, queue_size=10)
reset_joints = rospy.ServiceProxy('/gazebo/set_model_configuration', SetModelConfiguration)

def scene_resetter():
    rospy.init_node('scene_resetter', anonymous=True)
    random_joint_positions = [np.random.uniform(-0.79, 1.57), np.random.uniform(0.0, 1.57), \
        np.random.uniform(0.52, 2.09), np.random.uniform(-1.57, 1.57), \
        np.random.uniform(-0.52, 0.17), np.random.uniform(-0.70, 0.49), \
        np.random.uniform(-0.35, 0.35), np.random.uniform(0.0, 1.57), \
        np.random.uniform(0.0, 1.57), np.random.uniform(0.0, 1.57), \
        np.random.uniform(-0.35, 0.35), np.random.uniform(0.0, 1.57), \
        np.random.uniform(0.0, 1.57), np.random.uniform(0.0, 1.57), \
        np.random.uniform(-0.35, 0.35), np.random.uniform(0.0, 1.57), \
        np.random.uniform(0.0, 1.57), np.random.uniform(0.0, 1.57), \
        np.random.uniform(0.0, 0.79), np.random.uniform(-0.35, 0.35), \
        np.random.uniform(0.0, 1.57), np.random.uniform(0.0, 1.57), \
        np.random.uniform(0.0, 1.57), np.random.uniform(-1.05, 1.05), \
        np.random.uniform(0.0, 1.22), np.random.uniform(-0.21, 0.21), \
        np.random.uniform(-0.7, 0,7), np.random.uniform(0.0, 1.57)]

    # call gazebo service
    reset_req.joint_positions = random_joint_positions
    rospy.wait_for_service("/gazebo/set_model_configuration")
    reset_joints(reset_req)

    # publish init_joint_positions
    random_joint_states_msg.position = random_joint_positions
    random_joint_states_msg.header.stamp = rospy.Time.now() 
    pub_init_joint_positions.publish(random_joint_states_msg)   
    rospy.spin()


if __name__ == '__main__':
   scene_resetter()
```

However when I run the node, the following error message appears in the terminal:

```
 $ rosrun shadowrobot_control scene_resetter.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntubasic_roskinetic/shadow_try/src/shadowrobot_control/scripts/scene_resetter.py", line 83, in <module>
    scene_resetter()
  File "/home/ubuntubasic_roskinetic/shadow_try/src/shadowrobot_control/scripts/scene_resetter.py", line 73, in scene_resetter
    reset_joints(reset_req)
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/impl/tcpros_service.py", line 435, in __call__
    return self.call(*args, **kwds)
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/impl/tcpros_service.py", line 512, in call
    transport.send_message(request, self.seq)
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/impl/tcpros_base.py", line 665, in send_message
    serialize_message(self.write_buff, seq, msg)
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/msg.py", line 152, in serialize_message
    msg.serialize(b)
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gazebo_msgs/srv/_SetModelConfiguration.py", line 90, in serialize
    except struct.error as se: self._check_types(struct.error("%s: '%s' when writing '%s'" % (type(se), str(se), str(locals().get('_x', self)))))
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/genpy/message.py", line 336, in _check_types
    raise SerializationError(str(exc))
genpy.message.SerializationError: <class 'struct.error'>: 'required argument is not a float' when writing 'robot_description'
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I resolve this?

Thank you in advance!

Best,
Verena

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/303956/genpy.message.serializationerror-when-calling-service-/gazebo/set_model_configuration/) by [verena](https://answers.ros.org/users/37639/verena/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2018-09-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to the documentation ([here](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/gazebo_msgs/html/srv/SetModelConfiguration.html)), the `joint_positions` field is a list of `float64` elements.

You appear to be assigninging a list of numpy types to it.

That is ok with Python (as the interpreter itself doesn't care), but `genpy` can't work with those, hence the error.

---

Edit:

> Now I converted my numpy types to Float64, but the error remains.

`Float64` is a ROS msg type that *wraps* `float64` primitive types.

And `float64` is not a Python type. If you use `float(..)` it should work.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-09-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [verena](https://answers.ros.org/users/37639/verena/) on 2018-09-21**:
Thank you so much. Converting types did the trick! Because of the last line of the error message, I thought my problem was the type of 'robot_description'. Obviously, my guess was wrong. :)